# Composition of functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, function-and-relation-composition

If $h(x) = 2x + 1$, find $h(x + 2)$

...and a second question.

Given $f(x)=x^2+1,  g(x)=x-2$, then what is the domain of $f(g(x))$

$\begin{align}\text{Work: }
f(g(x)) & =(x-2)^2+1 
\\ & =(x-2)(x-2)+1 
\\ & =x^2-4x+4+1
\\ & =x^2-4x+5
\\ & ???\end{align}$

Comment: You've found what $f(g(x))$ is. $\checkmark$  Use the same process to find $h(k(x))$ where $k(x)=x+2$.

Comment: As to the domain of $f(g(x))$, it has definition everywhere in the real number field (also so in the complex field).

Answer (score 1):

$h(x + 2) = 2x+4 +1 = 2x+5$

As for the domain of the secnod, its all the Real line, since it had no undetermined points anywhere on the real line where the function cannot be determined (points where it would return the value infinity as output that is).